# Dependent Dropdown box CakePHP 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have created a countries, cities and customers table and i'm trying to ensure that when I add a new customer from a drop down I can select a country and then a city related to that country. Currently I am able t select any city and country combination from the drop down.
This is my database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `southpac_team`.`customers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `country_id` INT NULL,
  `city_id` INT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `postal_address` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `payment_terms_id` INT NULL,
  `stop_credit` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `gst_percentage` INT NULL,
  `currency` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_closed` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `invoice_email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `customer_notes` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `southpac_team`.`countries` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `southpac_team`.`cities` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I've used Cake Bake to create the relationships between the tables this is my customer controller.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Customers Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\CustomersTable $Customers
 */
class CustomersController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Countries', 'Cities', 'PaymentTerms']
        ];
        $customers = $this->paginate($this->Customers);

        $this->set(compact('customers'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['customers']);
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Customer id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $customer = $this->Customers->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Countries', 'Cities', 'PaymentTerms']
        ]);

        $this->set('customer', $customer);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['customer']);
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $customer = $this->Customers->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $customer = $this->Customers->patchEntity($customer, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Customers->save($customer)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The customer has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The customer could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $countries = $this->Customers->Countries->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $cities = $this->Customers->Cities->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $paymentTerms = $this->Customers->PaymentTerms->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('customer', 'countries', 'cities', 'paymentTerms'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['customer']);
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Customer id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $customer = $this->Customers->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $customer = $this->Customers->patchEntity($customer, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Customers->save($customer)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The customer has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The customer could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $countries = $this->Customers->Countries->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $cities = $this->Customers->Cities->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $paymentTerms = $this->Customers->PaymentTerms->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('customer', 'countries', 'cities', 'paymentTerms'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['customer']);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Customer id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $customer = $this->Customers->get($id);
        if ($this->Customers->delete($customer)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The customer has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The customer could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

and this is my customer add.ctp

```
<?php
/**
  * @var \App\View\AppView $this
  */
?>
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Customers'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Countries'), ['controller' => 'Countries', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Country'), ['controller' => 'Countries', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Cities'), ['controller' => 'Cities', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New City'), ['controller' => 'Cities', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Payment Terms'), ['controller' => 'PaymentTerms', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Payment Term'), ['controller' => 'PaymentTerms', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="customers form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($customer) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Customer') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
            echo $this->Form->input('country_id', ['options' => $countries, 'empty' => true]);
            echo $this->Form->input('city_id', ['options' => $cities, 'empty' => true]);
            echo $this->Form->input('address');
            echo $this->Form->input('postal_address');
            echo $this->Form->input('phone');
            echo $this->Form->input('email');
            echo $this->Form->input('payment_terms_id', ['options' => $paymentTerms, 'empty' => true]);
            echo $this->Form->input('stop_credit');
            echo $this->Form->input('gst_percentage');
            echo $this->Form->input('currency');
            echo $this->Form->input('account_closed');
            echo $this->Form->input('invoice_email');
            echo $this->Form->input('customer_notes');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

I am able to create new customers and select countries and cites I just want restrict the drop boxes so that I can only select a city for the correct country. I've tried to research this but have just come across examples using jshelper which cakephp 3.0 doesn't include.
Thanks.

Comment: you may use jquery Chained Library https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to install this onto my web server.

Comment: will do thanks Mark!

Comment: You might want to look into [chained dropdowns](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples) in the sandbox. Sry, the link was broken, now it is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Chained Selects Plugin for jQuery
[Chained Selects Plugin for jQuery and Zepto](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained)

Required Source files:

> ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
>   jquery.chained.min.js

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#cityId").chained("#countryId");
});
```

Comment: I tried this but I can't manage to get the chained plugin to work but i can get pop up messages using JQuery. I also tried following the example but it wont seem to work.