# CakePHP Chained Plugin Dropdown not linking

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cakephp, chained

I am trying to use the plugin Chained to restricted users from selecting a city for the wrong country. At the moment when I have no country selected it lets me choose from all the cities. But as soon as I select a country it will not let me select any cities. I've had this plugin working correctly using the code from the Chained website.
My broken countries/cities version can be seen here
login: guest
password: password
http://team.southpacificavionics.com/customers/add
and my test version can be seen if you change "add" on that url to "test" (sorry I cant post more links).
I've used ./cake bake to create my customers, countries and cities controllers, models, templates and key relationships.

[You can see from this image that the cities are linked to countries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjgxp.png)

This is my add.ctp for customers

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min'); ?>
 <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.chained'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cities").chained("#countries");
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('java is working');
    });
</script>

<?php
/**
  * @var \App\View\AppView $this
  */
?>

<div class="customers form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($customer) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Customer') ?></legend>

        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('country_id', ['options' => $countries, 'empty' => true,'id'=>'countries']);
            echo $this->Form->input('city_id', ['options' => $cities, 'empty' => true,'id'=>'cities']);

        ?>
    </fieldset>

    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

This is my mysql code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `southpac_team`.`customers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `country_id` INT NULL,
  `city_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `southpac_team`.`countries` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `southpac_team`.`cities` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: You posted same same thing at multiple time [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402533/dependent-dropdown-box-cakephp-3) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428535/using-chained-jquery-plugin) . you should not accept answer before the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add class at your city dropdown options yet you should **add country id as class in city dropdown**

[image: pic]

### How to add class in CakePHP Dropdown

```
$items = $this->Cities->find('all')->all()->toArray();
        $cities = [];
        foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
              $cities[$key]['value'] = $value['id'];
              $cities[$key]['text'] = $value['indent_no'];
              $cities[$key]['class'] = $value['country_id'];
        }
```

for more check [extra attribute in dorpdown](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers)

Comment: Do I need to create a CitiesHelper file because i'm unsure what code to put in the helper.

Comment: you may create dropdown from model or controller  which you set from controller named `$cities` variable

Comment: i think $cities is declared in the citiescontroller index i tried creating an initialize function and placing your code into it but had no success. Sorry i'm not very sure what i'm doing i'm still very new to this.

Comment: I placed it into the cities model and there doesnt seem to be any errors i just had to change $items = $this->Cities->find('all')->all()->toArray(); to $items = $this->find('all')->all()->toArray(); but i'm not sure how to test this to I need to make changes to my add.ctp?

Comment: I also found where $cities is set in the add function of the CutomersController         
//$cities = $this->Customers->Cities->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $items = $this->Cities->find->('all')->all()->toArray();
           $cities = [];
           foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
                $cities[$key]['value'] = $value['id'];
                $cities[$key]['text'] = $value['name'];
                $cities[$key]['class'] = $value['country_id'];
                } 
but when i added the code it says Call to a member function find() on boolean

Comment: Silly me I forgot to add 'Customers' in $items = $this->Customers->Cities->find->('all')->all()->toArray();
Thank you very much for your help!